# Using Rails 7, mail_form gem for Contact Us form and SendGrid. Mail sent successfully yet not receiving mail. in inbox

Tags: sendgrid, contact-form, ruby-on-rails-7, mail-form

Using rails 7, mail_form gem for 'contact us' page and sendGrid.
When I using Gmail settings for sending mail, it works and I get the 'contact us' form in my inbox but when I use sendGrid settings, it says the emails get sent but I don't see them in my inbox/junk/spam etc... folders.
I am currently using Devise for Users and either gmail settings or sendGrid settings work to send devise emails. I set my email address as 'primary sender' through sendGrid settings which is why I am successfully receiving Devise emails. I can't figure out 'contact us' form is being successfully sent via both gmail and sendGrid yet not receiving them in my inbox. I receive Devise emails fine.
Any ideas?

development.rb

```
# Don't care if the mailer can't send.
    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
    # config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    # :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    # :port => 587,
    # :user_name => 'ramona.kim@gmail.com',
    # :password => Rails.application.credentials.gmail_password,
    # :authentication => 'plain',
    # :enable_starttls_auto => true
    # }
    
    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :user_name => 'apikey', # This is the string literal 'apikey', NOT the ID of your API key
      :password => Rails.application.credentials.sendgrid_secret_api, # This is the secret sendgrid API key which was issued during API key creation
      :domain => Rails.application.credentials.domain,
      :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
      :port => 587,
      :authentication => :plain,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
   }
```

home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
# Landing page

    def contact
        @contact = Contact.new
    end

    def create_contact_message
        @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
        @contact.request = request
        if @contact.deliver
            flash[:success] = 'Message sent!'
            redirect_to action: :contact
        else
            flash[:error] = 'Could not send message'
            render :contact
        end
    end
end
```

models/contact.rb

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
    attribute :name,      validate: true
    attribute :email,     validate: /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
    attribute :subject,     validate: true
    attribute :message,     validate: true
    attribute :nickname,  captcha: true
  
    # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
    # in ActionMailer accepts.
    def headers
      {
        :subject => "Contact Form Inquiry",
        :to => "ramonakim@hotmail.com",
        :from => "ramonakim@hotmail.com" # <~ Primary send on sendGrid
      }
    end
end
```

contact.html.erb

```
<!-- Start Contact Form -->
            <div class="col-lg-8 ">
                <h3 class="text-center">Send a message</h3>
                <%= simple_form_for(@contact, method: :post, url: create_contact_message_path, defaults: { input_html: { class: 'contact-form row' } }) do |f| %>

                    <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
                        <div class="form-floating">
                            <%= f.input_field :name, class: 'form-control form-control-lg light-300', placeholder: 'Name' %>
                            <label for="floatingname light-300">Name</label>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- End Input Name -->

                    <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
                        <div class="form-floating">
                            <%= f.input_field :email, class: 'form-control form-control-log light-300', placeholder: 'Email' %>
                            <label for="floatingemail light-300">Email</label>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- End Input Email -->

                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                            <%= f.input_field :subject, class: 'form-control form-control-lg light-300', placeholder: 'Subject' %>
                            <label for="floatingsubject light-300">Subject</label>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- End Input Subject -->

                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <%= f.input_field :message, as: :text, class: 'form-control light-300', rows: '8', placeholder: 'Message', style: 'height: 200px'  %>
                            <label for="floatingtextarea light-300">Message</label>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- End Textarea Message -->

                    <div class="d-none">
                        <%= f.input :nickname %>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-12 m-auto text-end">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary rounded-pill px-md-5 px-4 py-2 radius-0 text-light light-300">Send Message</button>
                    </div>

                <% end %>
            </div>
            <!-- End Contact Form -->
```

console output after filling out contact form and submitting

```
14:59:10 web.1  | Started POST "/create_contact_message" for ::1 at 2022-06-09 14:59:10 -0700
14:59:10 web.1  |   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Pluck (0.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
14:59:10 web.1  | Processing by HomeController#create_contact_message as HTML
14:59:10 web.1  |   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "contact"=>{"name"=>"Some dude", "email"=>"somedude@example.com", "subject"=>"Hello", "message"=>"message here. blah.", "nickname"=>""}}
14:59:10 web.1  |   Rendering /home/ramona/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mail_form-1.9.0/lib/mail_form/views/mail_form/contact.erb
14:59:10 web.1  |   Rendered /home/ramona/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mail_form-1.9.0/lib/mail_form/views/mail_form/contact.erb (Duration: 2.7ms | Allocations: 1181)
14:59:10 web.1  | MailForm::Notifier#contact: processed outbound mail in 8.8ms
14:59:11 web.1  | Delivered mail 62a26d2e8148c_59d4378b4677d2@rk-7480.mail (1300.2ms)
14:59:11 web.1  | Date: Thu, 09 Jun 2022 14:59:10 -0700
14:59:11 web.1  | From: ramonakim@hotmail.com
14:59:11 web.1  | To: ramonakim@hotmail.com
14:59:11 web.1  | Message-ID: <62a26d2e8148c_59d4378b4677d2@rk-7480.mail>
14:59:11 web.1  | Subject: Contact Form Inquiry
14:59:11 web.1  | Mime-Version: 1.0
14:59:11 web.1  | Content-Type: text/html;
14:59:11 web.1  |  charset=UTF-8
14:59:11 web.1  | Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
14:59:11 web.1  | 
14:59:11 web.1  | <h4 style="text-decoration:underline">Contact Form Inquiry</h4>
14:59:11 web.1  | 
14:59:11 web.1  | 
14:59:11 web.1  |   <p><b>Name:</b>
14:59:11 web.1  |   Some dude</p>
14:59:11 web.1  | 
14:59:11 web.1  |   <p><b>Email:</b>
14:59:11 web.1  |   somedude@example.com</p>
14:59:11 web.1  | 
14:59:11 web.1  |   <p><b>Subject:</b>
14:59:11 web.1  |   Hello</p>
14:59:11 web.1  | 
14:59:11 web.1  |   <p><b>Message:</b>
14:59:11 web.1  |   message here. blah.</p>
14:59:11 web.1  | 
14:59:11 web.1  | 
14:59:11 web.1  | Redirected to http://localhost:3000/contact
14:59:11 web.1  | Completed 302 Found in 1339ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 10384)
14:59:11 web.1  | 
14:59:11 web.1  | 
14:59:11 web.1  | Started GET "/contact" for ::1 at 2022-06-09 14:59:11 -0700
14:59:11 web.1  | Processing by HomeController#contact as HTML
14:59:11 web.1  |   Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
14:59:11 web.1  |   Rendering home/contact.html.erb within layouts/application
14:59:11 web.1  |   Rendered home/contact.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 28.0ms | Allocations: 10826)
14:59:12 web.1  |   Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 1.2ms | Allocations: 370)
14:59:12 web.1  |   Rendered layouts/_flash.html.erb (Duration: 0.9ms | Allocations: 201)
14:59:12 web.1  |   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (Duration: 5.7ms | Allocations: 2302)
14:59:12 web.1  |   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 125.8ms | Allocations: 39002)
14:59:12 web.1  | Completed 200 OK in 132ms (Views: 129.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 40513)
14:59:12 web.1  | 
14:59:12 web.1  |
```

Comment: Are you sending your devise emails from the same email address you are sending the contact form (the hotmail address)? Is that address [verified as a single sender](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification) in SendGrid?

Comment: Yes. The Hotmail address is a verified single sender on SendGrid.

Comment: Are you sending your devise emails from the same email address you are sending the contact form?

Comment: Yes The Hotmail address is a verified single sender. Yes, when I filled out the contact form I also use my Hotmail address.

Comment: Can you try sending to a different email address?